# deploy replicas on multiple VMs

Tags: replication, mongodb

How do you set up a multi-node replica set in Mongodb? I don't know where to start. I'm trying to set up a replica set of three members in three virtual machines, i.e. there will be a total of three members, one for each virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps from the below links, If you face issues in setting up the replica set or any questions on the blog. Please add a comment with your issues.

[How to Setup MongoDB Replication](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-setup-mongodb-replication-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

[Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)